# Some functions of ckeditor in backend not shown in frontend

Tags: ckeditor

I tried ckeditor CDN and I installed the normal package. 
Problem: Some formatting or useful stuff like the spoiler function are visible and working in back-end, but once I saved a static file and watch it normally in front end of my website it just shows plain text without anything.

Doesn't affects everything, like colored text works, or linking and so on. But obviously I need all the stuff working, so can you help me please?

I have put the usual:

```
<script src="/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

In my back-end admin site ( where it works ), and in my **index.php** in front-end

Comment: Ive put the usual <script src="/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script> in my ......

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take some time to follow the [Stack Overflow tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Also provide us the relevant code you wrote for your question (You can also read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Comment: Do you have any errors shown in your dev console? Maybe missing style sheet(s)? Java errors? Placing example on jsfiddle will help people help you:)